# Primefaces / Internet Explorer: Credentials not saved

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces

In my JSF application I have a login form with username, password and captcha. Under Firefox and Chrome the users are able to save there credentials, but under Internet Explorer the credentials store dialog didn't came up. I tested this with IE9, IE10 and IE11.

This is the xhtml snippet (I have removed the panelGrid and message elements):

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:inputText id="benutzername" value="#{authenticate.username}"
        required="true" validatorId="inputValidator"
        styleClass="width_100p" />
    <br />
    <p:password id="passwort" value="#{authenticate.password}"
        required="true" validatorId="inputValidator"
        styleClass="width_100p" autocomplete="on" />
    <br />
    <p:captcha id="captcha" label="Captcha" theme="white"
        language="de" secure="true" />
    <br />
    <p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{authenticate.login()}"
        id="login" ajax="true" update="..."
        oncomplete="Recaptcha.reload()" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: I mean the browser-specific dialog to store login credentials like in any other browser. I tagged this question also with html, jsf and primefaces because I'm not sure where the problem really fits in.

Answer (score 0):

IE won't save credentials when:

1. You previously said the browser to never ask/remember on given URL.
2. At least one of inputs or even whole form has `autocomplete="off"`.
3. Form is submitted using JavaScript/Ajax.

To solve it:

1. Clear browse history.
2. Remove `autocomplete="off"` over all place.
3. Submit form synchronously, without JS/Ajax.

In your particular case, the form is clearly submitted using Ajax.